# LWC 3rd party script required to be loaded through a script tag

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am implementing an LWC that has a dependency on a third party resource that requires it to be loaded through a `script` tag.

As far as I can tell, 3rd party scripts must be uploaded as a static resource and loaded using `loadScript`. However this script that is needed is unique on every load and requires its configuration through [attributes](https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gw/merchants/resources/integration/integration_portal.php#cjs_integration_inline2) on the `script` tag.

I've tried loading it through a static resource and it just bombs out because some of the source code parses the script tag and it's not available.

Is there any possible work around to using scripts that require a script tag?

Comment: In the documentation you linked there exists an example of loading script without `data` attributes:
https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gw/merchants/resources/integration/integration_portal.php#cjs_example_inline2_js

What you'd do is put that `CollectJS.configure({` code inside the Promise from loading reference in LWC.

Most likely, however, your script `bombs` because it tries to access API not allowed by Lightning locker service. If you provide specific errors we may be able to help identify those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly in LWC (or, strictly speaking, in a Salesforce Lightning Component). This has to do with the CSP (Content Security Policy) of Lightning. You could choose to embed a Visualforce page in an `iframe` or use a `lightning:container` to host the relevant markup and then expose it in an Aura component (this container isn't available for LWC).